# Android rsSetElementAt 4.2

Tags: android, image, processing, renderscript

I am trying to find the min and max pixel values of my camera image using my renderscript. My render script file tries to call rsSetElementAt but I get the following warning:

C:\Users\tec\workspace\RSTestProject\src\com\myrs.rs:59:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'rsSetElementAt_uint' is invalid in C99

Since it was a warning I went ahead and ran the rs. The program crashed with the following error:

E/RenderScript: ScriptC sym lookup failed for rsSetElementAt_uint

WHAT'S Up with this? Thanks

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.techleadz.rstestproject)

rs_allocation gIn;
rs_allocation gOut;
rs_allocation gMin; // min matrix
rs_allocation gMax; // max matrix
bool reduce_constraints;
bool reset_constraints;
rs_script gScript;
//const uchar4 *gPixels;
int mode;

// this is invoked automatically
void init() {
    rsDebug( "initRS:", "mode" );
}

void filter() {
    rsDebug( "Number of Rows:", "mode" );
    rsForEach( gScript, gIn, gOut );
}

void RegisterPixels( const uchar4 *v_in, uchar4 *v_out, uint32_t column, uint32_t row ) {

    unsigned int input = (int)v_in;
    rsDebug( "Number of Rows:", rsAllocationGetDimX(gIn) );

    rsDebug("Printing out a Point", input);
    // see if this pixel exceeds the min and max

    // get an entire row if possible ????
    const uint *minRow = rsGetElementAt( gMin, row, column );
    const uint *maxRow = rsGetElementAt( gMax, row, column );

    uint newMinRow, newMaxRow;
    unsigned char minRowRed, minRowGreen, minRowBlue;
    unsigned char maxRowRed, maxRowGreen, maxRowBlue;

    minRowRed   = *minRow&0xff;
    minRowGreen = *minRow&0xff00 >> 8;
    minRowBlue  = *minRow&0xff0000 >> 16;
    maxRowRed   = *maxRow&0xff;
    maxRowGreen = *maxRow&0xff00 >> 8;
    maxRowBlue  = *maxRow&0xff0000 >> 16;

    // if reduce_constraints then do it first. This will force the constraints
    if( mode == 1 ) // gReduce_constraints == true ) {
    {
        // to recalculate as the sun rises or sets

        // go through the entire row
        minRowRed += 1; minRowGreen += 1; minRowBlue += 1;
        maxRowRed -= 1; maxRowGreen -= 1; maxRowBlue -= 1;

        // recombined RGB
        newMinRow = minRowRed & (minRowGreen<<8) & (minRowBlue<<16);
        newMaxRow = maxRowRed & (maxRowGreen<<8) & (maxRowBlue<<16);
        rsSetElementAt_uint( gMin, newMinRow, row, column );
        //rsSetElementAt_int( gMin, 0, 0 );
        //rsSetElementAt_uint( gMax, newMaxRow, row, column );
    }
    unsigned char inputRed = input&0xff;
    unsigned char inputGreen = (input&0xff00)>>8;
    unsigned char inputBlue = (input&0xff0000)>>16;
    // first see if this pixel is the wrong color
    // Brown deer are within a range of RGB values
    if( ( inputRed < 40 ) && ( inputRed > 218 ) ) return;
    if( ( inputGreen < 40 ) && ( inputGreen > 177 ) ) return;
    if( ( inputBlue < 40 ) && ( inputBlue > 167 ) ) return;

    if( ( inputRed > minRowRed ) && ( inputRed < maxRowRed ) ) {
        if( ( inputGreen > minRowGreen ) && ( inputGreen < maxRowGreen ) ) {
            if( ( inputBlue > minRowBlue ) && ( inputBlue < maxRowBlue ) ) {
                newMaxRow = newMaxRow | 0xff000000;
                v_out = newMaxRow;
                // place the hit in the upper byte
                //rsSetElementAt_int( gMax, newMaxRow, row, column );
            }
        }
    }

    return;
}

// the following RenderScript will find the min and max pixel
//void __attribute__((kernel))LearnArea( uint row ) {
void LearnArea( const uchar4 *v_in, uchar4 *v_out, uint32_t column, uint32_t row) {
    const unsigned int *lmin;
    const unsigned int *lmax;
    unsigned int newlmin;
    unsigned int newlmax;
    bool changed = false;
    rsDebug( "LearnArea:", rsAllocationGetDimX(gIn) );
    unsigned int input = (int)v_in;
    unsigned char inputRed   = input&0xff;
    unsigned char inputGreen = (input&0xff00)>>8;
    unsigned char inputBlue  = (input&0xff0000)>>16;

    if( reset_constraints == true) {
        rsSetElementAt_int( gMin, 255, row, column );
        //rsSetElementAt_int( gMax, 0, row, column );
    }
    else {
        lmin = rsGetElementAt( gMin, row, column );
        lmax = rsGetElementAt( gMax, row, column );

        unsigned char minRed   = *lmin&0xff;
        unsigned char minGreen = (*lmin&0xff00)>>8;
        unsigned char minBlue  = (*lmin&0xff0000)>>16;

        // see if the current pixel is less than the min
        changed = false;
        if( inputRed < minRed ) {
            minRed = inputRed;// red
            changed = true;
        }
        if( inputGreen < minGreen ) {
            minGreen = inputGreen; // green
            changed = true;
        }
        if( inputBlue < minBlue ) {
            minBlue = inputBlue;// blue
            changed = true;
        }

        if( changed == true ) {
            newlmin = minRed & (minGreen<<8) & (minBlue<<16);
            rsSetElementAt_int( gMin, newlmin, row, column );
        }

        unsigned char maxRed   = *lmax&0xff;
        unsigned char maxGreen = (*lmax&0xff00)>>8;
        unsigned char maxBlue  = (*lmax&0xff0000)>>16;

        changed = false;
        // see if the current pixel is less than the min
        if( inputRed < maxRed ) {
            maxRed = inputRed;// red
            changed = true;
        }
        if( inputGreen < maxGreen ) {
            maxGreen = inputGreen;// green
            changed = true;
        }
        if( inputBlue < maxBlue ) {
            maxBlue = inputBlue;// blue
            changed = true;
        }
        if( changed == true ) {
            newlmax = maxRed & (maxGreen<<8) & (maxBlue<<16);
            v_out =
            rsSetElementAt_int( gMax, newlmax, row, column );
        }
    }
    return;
}

/*
// use a radius to decide if a large area has exceed the thresholds
//void __attribute__((kernel))FindHits( uint rowCenter, uint cellSize, uint threshold )
void FindHits( uint rowCenter, uint cellSize, uint threshold )
{
    uint columnSum=0; // sum of the current sub column
    uint sums[cellSize]; // sum of a small column
    uint runningSum=0; // the sum of the cells_size x cell_size
    uint halfCellSize = cellSize/2;
    uint currentColumn=0;
    rsDebug( "FindHits:", rsAllocationGetDimX(gIn) ); // rsUptimeMillis()

    uint rowOffset = rowCenter - halfCellSize; // shortcut from doing this every iteration

    for( uint i=0; i < gWidth; i ++ ) {
        columnSum = 0;
        for( uint j=0; j < cellSize; j ++ ) {
            columnSum += rsElementGet_int( gHits, rowOffset + j, i );
        }
        if( i < cellSize ) {
            runningSum += columnSum;
        }
        else {
            // always subtract off the trailing column and add the current column
            runningSum = runningSum + columnSum - sums[currentColumn];
            if( runningSum > threshold ) {
                gMovementPresentRow = rowCenter;
                gMovementPresentColumn = i;
                return;
            }
            sums[currentColumn] = columnSum;
        }
        currentColumn ++;
        if( currentColumn > cellSize ) currentColumn = 0;
    }
    return;
}
*/

void root( const uchar4 *v_in, uchar4 *v_out, const void *usrData, uint32_t x, uint32_t y ) // v_out is the min/max
{
    rsDebug( "root:", "mode is" );
    if( mode == 0 )
    {
        RegisterPixels( v_in, v_out, x, y );
        rsDebug( "root:", "mode is 0" );
    }
    else if( mode == 1 )
    {
        //LeanArea( v_in, v_out );
        rsDebug( "root:", "mode is 1" );
    }
    else if( mode == 2 )
    {
        rsDebug( "root:", "mode is 2" );
        //FindHits( v_in, v_out );
    }
    else
        rsDebug( "root:", "mode is 3" );
```

Answer (score 3):

rsSetElementAt() and rsSetElementAt_*() are only available starting in target API 18. Since API 18 is not actually available on any Android device yet, you are not going to be able to properly execute this code until the next version of Android is released. I am not sure how you managed to get the function actually declared enough to compile (perhaps this is using the latest SDK?), but it is always going to fail to load on the device for now.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I will try to find a work around.I think my real issue is that I am asking one core to Set an element while other cores are operating on the buffers. I don't think RS allows all cores to operate on memory at the same time.

Comment: Is there a way to send back the java code a Boolean stating whether my min and max colors were exceeded? I want the pixel kernel to set the Boolean. I don't want the code to have to loop through all of the pixels on the CPU to test each pixel. I cannot figure out how to get a pixel level operator to set a Boolean back to the UI without sending back an 640x480 array of pixel booleans.

Comment: If all you want to know is whether one exceptional condition happened, you can create a single int in an Allocation and then use an atomic operation to set it to 1 (if the condition became true). You can then use Allocation.copyTo() to read it back into a single Java int.

Comment: One other note (since I work on RS): You can't have multiple cells in the ForEach kernel writing to the same locations during execution. That is definitely undefined behavior and is pretty much guaranteed to do the wrong thing for GPU execution (where you have an even greater number of threads active at one time).

Comment: You said "I can't have multiple cells writing to the same memory" but isn't that what's going to happen if the some of the cells writes to an integer that you suggested? Is a better way to use     RSMessageHandler l_resHandler = new RSMessageHandler()

Comment: You could use a message handler. If you do the write as I specified atomically (and it is only a transition from 0 -> 1 to indicate that you have exceeded the bounds), it is defined to work.

Comment: Is there an other way to rsSetElementAt_*() for older versions of android. I want the min and max values of a pixel to stay in GPU memory and not go back through the VM to my java code. I think it will run faster if I can keep the min/max values on the GPU. Can I index into the element some other way ? I need a work around. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no rsSetElementAt_*() for older versions because we can't go back and add it to every released Android device. Stay tuned for our compatibility library (briefly mentioned in this year's Google I/O talk). That will let you run the latest version of RS even on older devices (all the way back to Gingerbread).

Comment: But is there a way to write to the rs_allocation using pointers or array indexes in the rs? Can I access the "rs_allocation gMin" using another method like pointers or rsMemcpy?

Comment: There is no "memcpy" equivalent for RS, and pointers are only guaranteed to be linear for 1 dimension. Attempting to address a 2D Allocation with pointer arithmetic is usually going to be problematic for GPU drivers.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is of the renderScriptTargetApi. In order to use rsSetElementAt keep your renderScriptTargetApi to 18. Also, if problem persists, check all the parameters required for rsSetElementAt are having the exact datatype as provided in the documentation. In your case typecast row and column as
rsSetElementAt_int( gMax, newlmax, (uint32_t)row, (uint32_t)column );